# Regular expression for a mathematic expression

Tags: regex, string

I am trying to parse the following mathematical expressions by the **single** regular expression:

```
2(3(4+5)6)7
3(4+5)6
```

The expression should return `(3(4+5)6)7` for the first example and `(4+5)6` for the second. I created this:

`[\(\[].*[\(\]]*\d*`

but it is true only for the first case.

Is it possible to create a single regular expression for the above cases?

Comment: What are rules just match everything after first number?

Comment: After the first number, always bracket exists and it should take everything until this bracket is closed and plus a number (if it exists) after the reversed bracket.

Comment: Then you can just use `\(.+\)[0-9]*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the first `(` and the last `)` followed by only optional digits and specify the allowed characters in between.

```
\([\d+()-]+\)\d*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YIPTnZ/1)

If you can make use of PCRE, you could match balanced parenthesis and match the optional trailing digits.

```
(\((?>[\d+-]|(?1))*\))\d*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9qcq7f/1)